# $\mathbb{Z_4} \oplus \mathbb{Z_8} $ has a normal subgroup of index $16$ True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement is true/false ?

$\mathbb{Z_4} \oplus \mathbb{Z_8} $ has a normal subgroup of index $16$

My attempt : I thinks this is false here $ \mathbb{Z_2}$  is normal subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z_4}$ because index is $ 2 $ and $\mathbb{Z_4} $ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_8}$  so I think $\mathbb{Z_4} \oplus \mathbb{Z_8} $ has a normal subgroup of index $8$

Is its true ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is abelian,  so any subgroup of index $16$ will do.  So $\Bbb Z_2×\{e\}$.